# What is the 'Execution Context' in JavaScript exactly?

Tags: javascript

My title pretty much sums it all.

Can anyone enlighten me on...

**"What is the 'Execution Context' in JavaScript?"**

and on how it relates to 'this,' hoisting, prototype chaining, scope and garbage collection?

Comment: You probably need to define **Execution Context**

Comment: @jondavidjohn: *Execution context* has a specific meaning within [ECMA-262](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10).

Comment: When all else fails, there is always [the language specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10) to fall back on.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You're asking about several different concepts that aren't very closely related.  I'll try to briefly address each.

---

*Execution context* is a concept in the language spec that—in layman's terms—roughly equates to the 'environment' a function executes in; that is, variable scope (and the *scope chain*, variables in closures from outer scopes), function arguments, and the value of the `this` object.

The *call stack* is a collection of execution contexts.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7722057/201952) and [this article](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-1-execution-contexts/).

---

*Scope* is literally that: the scope in which a variable can be accessed.  Simplistically:

```
var x;

function a() {
    var y;
}
```

`x` can be accessed from anywhere.  When `a` is invoked, `x` will be in the outer scope.  (Stored in the *scope chain*.)

In contrast, `y` can only be accessed by code in `a()` because it is limited to `a`'s scope.  This is what the `var` keyword does: restricts a variable to the local scope.  If we omitted `var`, `y` would end up in the *global scope*, generally considered a bad thing.

---

Think of *hoisting* as more of a compile-time thing.  In JavaScript, function **declarations** are "hoisted" to the top of their scope.  In other words, they are parsed and evaluated *before* any other code.  (This is opposed to function **expressions**, which are evaluated inline.)  Consider the following:

```
a();
b();

function a() { }
var b = function() { }
```

The call to `a()` will succeed because its declaration was hoisted to the top; `a` was assigned to automatically before program execution began.  The call to `b()` will fail with a `TypeError` because `b` will not be defined until line 4.

Comment: Actually, regarding your bit on hoisting, the `b` variable declaration will also be hoisted: it'll be declared from the start, but no value will be assigned to it before line 4. Calling `b()` before line 4 will indeed result in an error, but a different one: we'll be trying to execute `undefined`, which isn't a function.

Comment: @josh3736 I really like your answer, but I don't understand is what causes stack to switch contexts like in an asynchronous function or a while loop where it apparently does not?

Comment: To be accurate `parsing` is just one part that our JS code experiences. while there are other parts that compose an action of Compilation - Lexer, parser, semantic analysis, optimizer, code generator. Better to change the semantics from `parsing` to `compiling`

reference: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921474/difference-between-compilers-and-parsers#:~:text=A%20parser%20just%20reads%20a,have%20to%20be%20machine%20code.

Comment: I have a question related to this question. After all, the code is executed and Execution Context is also popped from the call stack, now suppose the callback queue has some callback functions. Now when Execution Context is not there which has the `this` object how callbacks such as setTimeout are executing? Does it push Execution Context before a `cb()`?

Answer (score 26):

You have asked so many concepts but lets pick one by one & understand them.

*The environment in which your code is running is `Execution context`.* 
It is created when your code is executed.

`Execution Context (Global)`, created by JS Engine contains 3 important things for you:

1. Global object - `window`
2. Special Object `this`
3. Ref to outer environment

Lets see a simple example to understand `Global Execution Context`:

```
var a = "Hello World";

function b(){

}
```

When JS Engine runs this above code it creates following Execution context (shown in image):
[Global Execution Context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyJqV.png)

---

Now let's see how JS Engine creates `Execution Context` (then we will dig out & understand hoisting):
consider this scenario:

```
b();
console.log(a);

var a = "Hello World!";
function b(){
    console.log("Called b!");
}
```

I can call the function `b()` even though it is declared later.
This means JS Engine is doing something before my code is executed, lets see what:

JS Engine performs following two steps to while executing any code:

**CREATION PHASE** :

- JS Engine parses - run through your code & `identifies variables & functions` created by code (which will be used in execution phase)
- Setup memory space for Variables & Functions - **"Hoisting"**
- **Hoisting** - before your code is executed, the JS Engine set asides memory space for Var & Func used inside the code.
  These variables & functions comprise the Execution Context of any function that is be executed.
  All variables in JS are initially set to undefined.

**Execution PHASE:** pretty simple to understand,

- When the code is executed line-by-line (by JS interpreeter) it can
  access the variables defined inside Execution Context
- variable assignment are done in this phase

***A new Execution Context is created whenever function invocation is there***

**Execution Context Stack:**
What happens when you invoke a function:

```
function b(){

}

function a(){
    b();
}

a();
```

- Now first of all `Global Execution Context` is going to be created
  (as explained above)
- then execution starts and interpreeter encounters `call to function
  a()`, and `here a new execution context is created pushed on top EC
  Stack`

  *so anytime you invoke a function a new EC is created & placed on top of EC Stack.*
- so now `EC for a()` is `CREATED` interpreeter will execute the code
  inside `a()` line-by-line
- then intrepreeter encounters `call to function b()`, this creates
  another `EC` which is pushed on top or `EC` stack
- When `b()` finishes it will be popped-off the stack then `a()` will finish &
  all the way down to `Global EC`

[see Execution Stack for above code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QZQW.png)

Comment: For more information see here http://davidshariff.com/blog/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript/

Answer (score 9):

I have addressed *only* the topics that are most closely related.

Execution Context is the *wrapper* around your existing code; which contains code *that you have not written*; but is generated by the **JS Engine.**

It comprises of the following -

1. Global Object
2. 'this'
3. Outer environment
4. *Your* code

---

An Execution Context is created each time you run your .js file/app. The first step in this creation phase is **Hoisting**. The JS Engine *reserves space* or *set's up memory* for all the variables and functions defined in *your* code. These are then accessed when your code is executed line-by-line.

For example:

```
b();
console.log(a);
var a = "hi!";
function b() {
    console.log("calling function");
}
```

Here, the *function b()* and *variable a* are both accessed before they are defined, however, due to **hoisting** the console will not throw any error.

The output will look like - (try it)

```
calling function
undefined
```

Notice how the function was executed completely, but we have **undefined** for the variable. This is because *Hoisting* is performed differently for functions vs variables. The function as a whole is picked up into the memory, but for the variables, space is reserved as a *placeholder* with the value of **undefined**. The actual value is then replaced when the engine executes *your* code line-by-line.

I hope this clears the concept for you.

Answer (score 9):

I would like to address

1. Context
2. this context (relation with context)
3. Scope

**1 : Execution Context**

JavaScript is a single threaded language, meaning only one task can be executed at a time. When the JavaScript interpreter initially executes code, it first enters into a **global execution context by default**. Each invocation of a function from this point on will result in the creation of a new execution context.

This is where confusion often sets in, the term **execution context** is actually for all intents and purposes referring more to scope and not context. It is an unfortunate naming convention, however it is the terminology as defined by the ECMAScript specification, so we’re kinda stuck with it.

Each time a **new execution context** is created it is appended to the top of the execution stack. The browser will always execute the current execution context that is atop the execution stack. Once completed, it will be removed from the top of the stack and control will return to the execution context below.

An execution context can be divided into a creation and execution phase. In the creation phase, the interpreter will first create a variable object (also called an activation object) that is composed of all the variables, function declarations, and arguments defined inside the execution context. From there the scope chain is initialized next, and the value of this is determined last. Then in the execution phase, code is interpreted and executed.

**2 : this Context**

What is “this” Context?
Context is most often determined by how a function is invoked. When a function is called as a method of an object, this is set to the object the method is called on:

```
var obj = {
    foo: function() {
        return this;   
    }
};

obj.foo() === obj; // true
```

The same principle applies when invoking a function with the new operator to create an instance of an object. When invoked in this manner, the value of this within the scope of the function will be set to the newly created instance:

```
function foo() {
    alert(this);
}

foo() // window
new foo() // foo
```

When called as an unbound function, this will default to the global context or window object in the browser. However, if the function is executed in strict mode, the context will default to undefined.

**3 : Variable scope**

A variable can be defined in either **local or global scope**, which establishes the variables’ accessibility from different scopes during runtime. Any defined global variable, meaning any variable declared outside of a function body will live throughout runtime and can be accessed and altered in any scope. Local variables exist only within the function body of which they are defined and will have a different scope for every call of that function. There it is subject for value assignment, retrieval, and manipulation only within that call and is not accessible outside of that scope.

ECMAScript 6 (ES6/ES2015) introduced the **let and const** keywords that support the declaration of block scope local variables. This means the variable will be confined to the scope of a block that it is defined in, such as an if statement or for loop and will not be accessible outside of the opening and closing curly braces of the block. This is contrary to var declarations which are accessible outside blocks they are defined in. The difference between let and const is that a const declaration is, as the name implies, constant - a read-only reference to a value. This does not mean the value is immutable, just that the variable **identifier cannot be reassigned**.

**For Other topics:**
GC : [GC](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/7242ka/garbage_collection_unwanted_memory_access_in_js/)
Prototyping : [Prototyping](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/1m3yyl/javascript_best_practice_function_or/)

Answer (score 0):

The "Execution Context" is an umbrella that wraps all of the code to help manage it. It's like a manager that manages any environment.  Since there's so many lexical environments because in a JavaScript application you have lots of variables and functions you need a way to manage everything. What comes first, what comes second and so on, and if you did not have an "Execution Context" environment everything goes to hell.  So consider the "Execution Context" a wrapper, a manager that manages your code.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a function you create a new `execution context` comprising a local memory which is called a `variable environment` and `this` which is a placeholder, it will refer inside its execution context to whatever is the left of the `.` where that function is being called upon.

Answer (score -1):

> what is EC(Execution context) in JS ?
>
> Simply put, an execution context is an abstract concept of an
>   environment where the Javascript code is evaluated and executed.
>   Whenever any code is run in JavaScript, it’s run inside an execution
>   context.

For more depth details : https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-execution-context-and-execution-stack-in-javascript-1c9ea8642dd0

Answer (score -3):

I suppose a simple example would explain everything.

*Note: `function.call(object)` calls function `function` in context of `object`*

```
// HTML

​<p id="p"></p>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

// JavaScript

function helloWorld() {
    alert("HelloWorld: " + this);
}

var p = document.getElementById("p");
helloWorld();                // HelloWorld: [object DOMWindow]
helloWorld.call(window);     // HelloWorld: [object DOMWindow]
​​​​​​helloWorld.call("String");   // HelloWorld: String // Note: "toString()"
helloWorld.call​​​​(p);          // HelloWorld: [object HTMLParagraphElement]
helloWorld.call(new Date());​​​​ // HelloWorld: Tue Feb 21 2012 21:45:17 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time)
```

Comment: This answer is pretty informative. call() is a property of the function prototype. It can be called on any function. Since helloWorld() basically does a var_dump() of the passed object's this property, you'll be told the value of this for any value you pass in. ... and that is what is sometimes difficult about javascript. It's easy to lose your place in the scope chain.

Comment: The OP asked about 'execution context' not 'context'.  'Execution context' has a very specific definition in the ECMAScript spec including 'Lexical Environments', 'outer' Lexical Environment reference, 'Environment Records', the stack, program control and the internal [[Scope]] property on functions.

Answer (score -3):

Execution Context is a wrapper to help manage the code that is running.
In your code you will see lots of lexical environments (which means areas of the code between `{ ... }`) but which one is currently running is managed via execution contexts. It can contain your code and it also can contain beyond what you've written in your code.