# Local Javascript scoping issue

Tags: javascript, scope

If I do this:

```
var a = 0;

(function () {
    var a = a; //want to make local a = global a
    ++a;
    console.log("fn",a);
})();

console.log(a);​
```

The output is:

```
fn NaN
0
```

Why does `a` inside of the self executing function become `NaN`?

I know it works fine if I do:

```
(function () {
    var b = a;
    ++b;
    console.log("fn",b); // fn 1
})();
```

But if I go the way of the first version, it has the `NaN` issue.

Why is this happening?

Comment: i am not sure why it does that but i tried using  `var a = window.a` and it behaves appropriately

Comment: @Ibu hmmm that is odd...

Comment: because all global variables are in window scope

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`var a = a;` is actually `var a; a = a;` due to variable hoisting. This means at the time of the assignment the old `a` is already shadowed by the new one (which is `undefined`).

The easiest way to avoid issues like that is passing the value as a parameter:

```
(function (a) {
    ++a;
    console.log("fn",a);
})(a);
```

In case `a` is a global variable you could also use `var a = window.a;` like [woz suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11457501/298479) - but since having global variables is usually a bad idea better stay with the parameters.

Comment: So how would I make it so that my local variable and global variable are equal at the start of the local function scope? Do I need to use a temp variable?

Comment: See my edit. You cannot use a temporary variable for this since no matter what you do, as soon as there is `var a` in your function the outer `a` is not accessible anymore.

Comment: Ooohh  I forgot about parameters :-P Duuuuh. `+1`

Answer (score 6):

The `a` variable inside your function expression *shadows* the `a` variable declared on the outer scope.

It becomes `NaN`, since in the assignment:

```
var a = a;
```

The right-side `a` it's actually referring to the `a` in the local scope.

Variable declarations are done before the function actually starts to be executed, this is commonly known as 'hoisting'.

Since it's the same variable, it holds the `undefined` value, and when you try to add any number to this value, it becomes `NaN`:

```
console.log(undefined + 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, the current [*execution context*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9384894/201952) (which includes things like variable scope) is established *before* your code begins executing.

What this means to you is that your local variable names are allocated first.  Due to *hoisting*, labels from `var` statements *anywhere in the function* are initialized to *undefined* in the current execution context.  (*Function statements* are also initialized in this step.)

Next, your code actually begins executing.  The `a` label is already reserved in the current execution context, so `var a = a;` simply assigns the local `a` (which is *undefined*) to itself.

`var a = window.a` works because you sidestep the scope issue by accessing global scope directly.  However, this doesn't work in non-browser environments (like Node) because there is no `window`; the global object in Node is `global`.

Answer (score 0):

there is a variable hoisting in javascript, so your code during execute looks like this:

```
(function () {
    var a;
    a = a; //want to make local a = global a
    ++a;
    console.log("fn",a);
})();
```

so firstly you have local variable a as undefined and then you assign undefined to variable a