# JavaScript Image onload not called

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I'm trying to draw an image on the Canvas in Javascript, but ofcourse I want to wait until the image is loaded. However, my onload function seems to be never called.

Here is what I've tried:

```
function GameObject(x, y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.image = {};
    this.loaded = false;

    this.load = function(filename)
    {
        this.image = new Image();
        this.image.onload = function()
        {
            alert("image loaded");
            this.loaded = true;
        };
        this.image.src = filename;
    };
};
```

I'm calling the load function like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function()
{
    main();
});

var player = new Player(0, 0);

function main()
{
    player.load("images/player.png");
};
```

and Player inherits from GameObject.

When using FireBug, it looks like the image is loaded, however the alert "image loaded" is never shown and this.loaded remains false.

What could be wrong?

*EDIT*: The image is now loaded (there was an error in the path name), but this.loaded is never set to true, while the alert is called.

Comment: Can we see more code ? Did you check the filename and that the image is received ?

Comment: The filename is correct. How exactly would I check if it is received? I will edit my post with some more code.

Comment: A solution is to have a look at the network tab of your in browser developer tools.

Comment: Add an onerror event, see if it gets triggered.

Comment: I think image is cached and that's why onload does not get called

Comment: @karaxuna Even when the image is cached the load event is called.

Comment: epascarello, an error is indeed triggered. How do I check what error it is?

Comment: What's the purpose of this statement: `this.image;`?

Comment: @mhu, that was a typo, I've corrected it, but the problem still exists.

Comment: @RaptorDotCpp `yourImage.onerror = function (error) { console.log(error); }`

Comment: @RaptorDotCpp look at the arguments passed in.

Comment: I've updated my post, the alert is shown, but this.loaded is not set to true. Is it possible to use the this keyword from that context?

Comment: I think your setting the 'loaded' property on the image rather than the parent object, so player.loaded will remain false.

Comment: Indeed. I solved it by passing the player as an argument to the function. However, that feels like a hack. How would I access the GameObject object from within the image.onload function? Can I pass it as an argument to onload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look for `loaded` field in `player.image` object.

In order to `loaded` be assigned to the `player` object you should rewrite part of your code like this:

```
this.load = function(filename)
{
    var self = this;
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.onload = function()
    {
        alert("image loaded");
        self.loaded = true;
    };
    this.image.src = filename;
};
```

The problem is that when `onload` is called the [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384758/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript-exactly) (to what `this` points) is the `image` object. So you have to save your initial context in the `self`.

Answer (score 1):

you may think that it's a hard way but believe me it's not:
if you want to use jQuery load Event for images let me tell you a truth : "That Is a SHIT" so you should use :

```
.imagesLoaded()
```

but before using that you should first download it [here](https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/)
after downloading do these steps:

1. attach your .imagesLoaded() library js file into your first code as you did for main jQuery.js
2. write this code for the image you want to check if loaded or not:

   ```
   $('#container').imagesLoaded()
   .always( function( instance ) {
    console.log('all images loaded');
   })
   .done( function( instance ) {
   console.log('all images successfully loaded');
   })
   .fail( function() {
   console.log('all images loaded, at least one is broken');
   })
   .progress( function( instance, image ) {
   var result = image.isLoaded ? 'loaded' : 'broken';
   console.log( 'image is ' + result + ' for ' + image.img.src );
   });
   ```
3. put the address of you picture instead of #container in the code
   ENJOY:))