# Window having properties not defined yet and those are defined as undefined

Tags: javascript

So, I was writing a function that determined the differences between the starting `window`, and the new `window` whenever the function is called. However, nothing was logged:

```
var differences = (function() {
    var original = {};
    for (var i in window) {
        if (window.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            original[i] = window[i];
        }
    }

    // this is the area I refer to further down in my post

    return function() {
        // should find differences between original and new window
        for (var i in window) {
            if (!(original.hasOwnProperty(i)) && window.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                console.log(i + ": " + window[i]);
            }
        }
    };
})();

var abc = 5;
differences(); // nothing is logged
```

So, I decided to check what `abc` was in the original copy:

```
// after first for loop in foo differences function
console.log(original.hasOwnProperty("abc")); // true
console.log(original.abc);
// this logs that abc is defined as undefined
```

One would think that because `differences` is defined first, that `abc` shouldn't exist in the `original` Object. But, since it does exist in the `original` Object, why is it defined as `undefined` and not 5?

But, what confuses me even more is the `hasOwnProperty` line I wrote

```
console.log(original.hasOwnProperty("abc"));
```

when ran in JSFiddle it logs `false`, but if I make a blank HTML file with JS, it logs `true`.

Can someone explain these odd occurrences?

Comment: jsfiddle runs in an `<iframe>`

Comment: you probably want to declare abc as `window.abc = 5;` ?

Comment: @le_m But isn't the default scope `window`?

Comment: I'd suggest reverting the edit since it's not a problem of running code inside an iframe

Comment: @anonymous It works with a) `abc = 5;` and b) `window.abc = 5;` but not c) `var abc = 5;`. Explanation: a) is declared after `var difference = ...;` due to the hoisting rules and b) is just an assignment and hoisting doesn't occur here.

Comment: @anonymous Note, there should not be any differences at the properties of `original` and `window`; `if` condition at `!(original.hasOwnProperty(i))` should return `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare a variable using `var` it gets added to the most immediate [execution context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384758/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript-exactly) **before any code is executed** (this is known as *hoisting* by the way if you want to search on the topic)

Imagine the following

```
function foo() {
  // note that the following doesn't throw an error
  console.log(bar)   // undefined
  var bar = 5
  console.log(bar)   // 5
}
foo()
console.log(bar)   // throw an error
```

When the function is called the following steps occur internally

- An execution context is created
- All the functions/variable declarations get defined on the execution context
- The code is executed

If the variable is defined outside a function then its most immediate execution context is the global context which in web browsers is the `window` object

```
  // note that the following doesn't throw an error
  console.log(bar)          // undefined
  console.log(window.bar)   // undefined      
  console.log(window.hasOwnProperty('bar'))   // true
  var bar = 5
  console.log(bar)   // 5
  console.log(window.bar)   // 5
```

> But, what confuses me even more is the hasOwnProperty line I wrote
>   `console.log(original.hasOwnProperty("abc"));`
>   when ran in JSFiddle it logs false, but if I make a blank HTML file with JS, it logs true.
>
> Can someone explain these odd occurrences?

The problem with JSFiddle is **not that the code is run on an iframe**, it's that the code you write is put inside a function by JSFiddle, if you inspect the iframe created by JSFiddle you will see the following

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <script>
//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
console.log(window.hasOwnProperty('bar'))  // false
var bar = 5
}//]]> 
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

However if your code is inside a `script` tag or in an external script just like you did with a blank html you get the following

```js
console.log(window.hasOwnProperty('bar'))  // true
var bar = 5
```

Comment: That is really interesting, thank you for the thorough answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an IIFE where `original` is passed to an object which includes function to be called. Note, `!(original.hasOwnProperty(i))` would return `false`, `console.log(i + ": " + window[i])` would not be called in second `for` loop, as properties of `window` were previous set at `original`.

You can remove `!` operator at `if` condition within second `for` loop, call function returned at object to view results of `console.log(i + ": " + window[i])`; return `original` as value of property at same object to determine if `abc` is defined at both `original` and `window`

```
var differences = (function() {
    var original = {};
    for (var i in window) {
        if (window.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            original[i] = window[i];
        }
    }

    // this is the area I refer to further down in my post  
    return {
        props: function() {
            return (function(original) {
                // should find differences between original and new window
                for (var i in window) {
                    if ((original.hasOwnProperty(i)) && window.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                        console.log(i + ": " + window[i]);
                    }
                }
                ;
            }(original)) 
        },
        o: original
    };
})();

var abc = 5;
var diff = differences;
diff.props();
console.log(window["abc"], diff.o["abc"])
```

Comment: I'm confused, why would I not want `!(original.hasOwnProperty(i))`? To detect differences between two objects, you check to see if one object has a property and the other one doesn't.

Comment: @anonymous  _"why would I not want `!(original.hasOwnProperty(i))`? To detect differences between two objects, you check to see if one object has a property and the other one doesn't."_ You can include `!` operator before `(original.hasOwnProperty(i))`. No properties should be logged at `console.log(i + ": " + window[i]);` at second `for` loop, as `if` condition should return `false`