# Primeng data table loading not working

Tags: angular, primeng

I have data table with list of data. I want to display loading icon indicates that data is loading. I can able to display data, But not showing loading icon.

### my html

```
 <p-dataTable [value]="stuList" [rows]="10" [paginator]="true" [loading]="loading" [totalRecords]="totalRecords" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[50,100,150]" [pageLinks]="3" sortMode="multiple" [(selection)]="selectedData"  selectionMode="single" expandableRows="true">
//coulmns
</p-dataTable>
```

### My Service class

```
 import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response,Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {Student} from './student';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class StudentService {
private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
student:Student;
url:any='http:localhost:3002/getStudents';
constructor(private http: Http) {}
//Rest Call
getData(): Observable<Student[]>{
return this.http.get(this.url)
.map(this.extractData)
.catch(this.handleError);
}
private extractData(res: Response) {
let body = res.json();
return body.data.request as Student[];
}
}
```

### My table component

```
 import { Component,OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { StudentService } from './studentservice.component'
import { Student} from './student'
import { Router }    from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'data-grid',
templateUrl: '../app/datagrid.html',
styleUrls: ['../app/datagrid.css']
})
@Injectable()
export class StudentDataGrid implements OnInit {
datasource:Student[];
stuList:Student[];
selectedData:Student; 
@Input()
loading: boolean;
totalRecords:number;
constructor(private studentService:StudentService, private router:Router) {      }
ngOnInit() {
this.loading = true;
//Rest call
this.studentService.getData().subscribe(stuList => {
this.datasource = stuList;
this.totalRecords = this.datasource.length;
this.stuList = this.datasource;
this.loading = false;
}); 
}
```

### My App Module class

```
 import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService }  from './in-memory-data.service';
import { AppComponent }         from './app.component';
import {DataTableModule,SharedModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {DialogModule} from 'primeng/primeng';

@NgModule({
imports: [BrowserModule,FormsModule,HttpModule,InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService,{passThruUnknownUrl:   true}),
AppRoutingModule,DataTableModule,SharedModule,DialogModule ],
declarations: [],providers: [],bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]})
export class AppModule { }
```

when I tried above code, showing below error.

Can't bind to 'loading' since it isn't a known property of 'p-dataTable'.
1. If 'p-dataTable' is an Angular component and it has 'loading' input, then  verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-dataTable' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to     the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Am I missing something? Please help

Comment: Which version primeng do you use?

Comment: Primeng4.0.0-rc.3

Comment: If possible share app.moudle.ts(Where you kept @NgModule) and p-table used component ts and html code...

Comment: Can you show your module where do you use the DataTable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this by upgrading my Angular2 to angular4 and Primeng2 to primeng4

Need to use PrimeNG-4.we can check change logs after each release;

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-4-0-0-rc3-released/

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2395

Answer (score 0):

I don't use angular 2 yet. but i think you must place 

this.loading = false 

inside the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `@Input` declarator before the `loading` property. It's needs to be imported from `@angular/core`.

Comment: Can you publish the entire code for p-dataTable component please.

Comment: @stackUser44 remove @Injectable() from your component class, there should be no other but classes following declaration segment. Also @Injectable() should never be used in view components anyways.

Comment: Removed, But still getting the same error  " If 'p-dataTable' is an Angular component and it has 'loading' input, then verify that it is part of this module."

Comment: Have you declared StudentDataGrid in the DataTableModule?

Comment: Yes, declared and able to show data. But unable to display loading icon. instead its showing as "No records found". After some time its fetching the data and displaying as i am getting huge data.

Comment: If I remove [loading]="loading" its working. or else showing same error

Comment: You need to supply the code for p-dataTable not data-grid. That's the component that is giving you error.

Comment: In that component add @Input before loading, make sure to import it from @angular/core and see that it it's properly declared in the relevant module.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , you don't need timer function,
Before calling make loading true, on your angular service callback you can make it false.

Inside *setTimeout* call back function **"this"** is different object,
Please see this link for execuation context in js.
[What is the 'Execution Context' in JavaScript exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384758/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript-exactly)

```
 import {DataTableModule,SharedModule,DialogModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
    ngOnInit() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.carService.getCarsSmall().then(cars =>{
                    this.cars = cars;
                    this.loading = false;
        });

}
```

Showing loading mask, there are different ways, you can search for spinner in Angular 2 and then you can hook to all http calls, you don't need manually write for each http call again.