# Are stack frame and execution context the same thing in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how the JavaScript environment works in the browser.About the call stack I've found some different definitions:

> A call stack is **composed of stack frames.**
>   [Explain the concept of a stack frame in a nutshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057443/explain-the-concept-of-a-stack-frame-in-a-nutshell)

and

> The call stack is a **collection of execution contexts.**[What is the 'Execution Context' in JavaScript exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384758/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript-exactly)

Are this things the same in JavaScript? I mean, they represents the same structure?

Comment: Could you cite these quotes to give a little bit more context?  It would be helpful to see if they give definitions for "stack frames" and "execution contexts" just to be sure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384758/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript-exactly  and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057443/explain-the-concept-of-a-stack-frame-in-a-nutshell

Comment: Yes, they are different terms for the same thing.