# What's difference inner function and parameter function in scope chain?

Tags: javascript, executioncontext, javascript-scope

I know that the execution context of JavaScript is created when a function is called. But I don't understand example below. Example 1 and Example 2 are very similar.

However, these results are not the same.

I already referenced the links.[You-Don't-Konw JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/README.md#you-dont-know-js-scope--closures) and [Blog reference](https://medium.com/koderlabs/javascript-scope-chain-and-execution-context-simplified-ffb54fc6ad02) and [related to stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384758/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript-exactly)

#### Example 1

```js
var value = "Hello";

function bar() {
  var value = "Bye";

  function foo() {
    return value;
  }

  console.log(foo());
}

bar(); // Bye
```

#### Example 2

```js
var value = "Hello";

function foo() {
  return value;
}

function bar(func) {
  var value = "Bye";
  console.log(func());
}

bar(foo); // Hello
```

I expected both results example 1 and example 2 to be Bye. If the execution context of the JavaScript is created at the time of the function call, why are the two results different?

Answer (score 0):

The closure depends upon where the function was created not where it was called. The function `foo` in example 2 have no access to the local variable `value` of function `bar`. So therefore due to closure the value returned from `foo` is `value` of global scope.

Answer (score 0):

The two `value`s here are different; they're just named the same. You can think of them as `value` in the global scope, and `value` in the scope of `bar`. Like having identically named files in two different directories, they're not actually the same.